# C macro to test: "If more than one defined"

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I have several drivers using a resource in my code, of which only one can be defined.
eg if I have the following defines:  USB_HID, USB_SERIAL, USB_STORAGE.
and I want to test that only one is defined, is there a simple way to do this?
Currently I am doing it this way:

```
#ifdef USB_HID
  #ifdef USB_INUSE
    #error "Can only have one USB device"
  #else
    #define USB_INUSE
  #endif
#endif

#ifdef USB_SERIAL
  #ifdef USB_INUSE
    #error "Can only have one USB device"
  #else
    #define USB_INUSE
  #endif
#endif
```

...
with one of these blocks for each USB_XXX driver.
Is there  more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#if defined(USB_HID) + defined(USB_SERIAL) + defined(USB_STORAGE) != 1
#error Define exactly one of USB_HID, USB_SERIAL, USB_STORAGE
#endif
```

Comment: Nice solution. I probably would have ended up with a nasty mash of  && || operators.

Comment: Really nice, +1. @Mike Weller: me too :)

Comment: Legend answer, I was awash in operators before I saw this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `define` operator such as:

`#if defined (USB_HID) && defined (USB_INUSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not #elif ?

```
#if defined(USB_HID)
   #define USB_INUSE
#elif defined(USB_SERIAL)
   #define USB_INUSE
#endif
```